# Entity Framework Enable-Migrations Null Reference Exception

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-migrations

I'm unable to get Code First migrations working properly on my Visual Studio 2013 project. I'm using EF 6.1 and C#.Net 4.5. When I try to run `Enable-Migrations` or `Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName DataContext` I get the following error:

```
PM> Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName DataContext -Force
Checking if the context targets an existing database...
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Infrastructure.DataAccess.DataContext..ctor() in c:\Users\mblack\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BluemoonApp\Infrastructure\DataAccess\DataContext.cs:line 16
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbContextInfo.CreateInstance()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbContextInfo..ctor(Type contextType, DbProviderInfo modelProviderInfo, AppConfig config, DbConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Func1 resolver)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration, DbContext usersContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState, Boolean calledByCreateDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration configuration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.MigrationScaffolder..ctor(DbMigrationsConfiguration migrationsConfiguration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.ScaffoldInitialCreate(String language, String rootNamespace)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.EnableMigrationsCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I cannot figure out why this won't work. I've tried re-installing EntityFramework via Nuget Package Manager Console, as well as deleting the Migrations folder then trying to "Re-Enable" migrations.

Please let me know if there's any additional information you need, thanks

EDIT: Adding DataContext.cs and DataContextInitializer.cs

```
namespace Infrastructure.DataAccess
{
    public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DataContext()
            : base(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BluemoonDev"].ConnectionString)
        {
            Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        }

        public virtual DbSet<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Test> Tests { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Core.Models.Configuration> Configurations { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Subscriber> Subscribers { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            //modelBuilder.Entity<Task>().HasKey(t => t.TaskId);


            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
}

namespace Infrastructure.DataAccess
{
    public class DataContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DataContext>
    {
        protected override void Seed(DataContext context)
        {
            // . . . Creating lists for each Entity
            // . . . Adding those items to context and saving changes
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the package manager console drop down pointing to the project with the context?

Comment: Yes, it's Default Project is Infrastructure and my DataContext.cs file is within Infrastructure.DataAccess

Comment: What does your data context and initializer look like?

Comment: They've been editted into the post

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but instead of getting the connection string from `ConfigurationManager`, you could simply use the name. E.g. `base("BluemoonDev")`

Comment: I've checked that the `ConfigurationManager` correctly grabs the string using the debugger, and I have it setup that way for configuring the database in the config file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use migrations you need to change your initializer to MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion or NullDatabaseInitializer. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx#initializer

Comment: When I try to run the `Enable-Migrations` command it still fails (I'm using `NullDatabaseInitializer`).

Comment: I don't even see a concrete need for migrations, but my context hasn't been working properly so I figured I'd give it a shot.

Comment: OK, well if that's not working I'd look at higher level issues like configuration. Try changing your ctor to base("BluemoonDev") as jrummell suggested. Also, check rights to DropCreate. Is this SQL Server or LocalDb?

Comment: What issues are you running into with your context not related to migrations?

Comment: Currently I have a slew of problems, one of which is insufficient permissions to run the `CREATE DATABASE` query. I'm working on figuring it out

Comment: It looks like while attempting to use `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` I have accidentally deleted my user...

Comment: I work in a restricted environment where the DBA sets it up. So I use CreateDatabaseIfNotExists during dev and then switch to migrations later on.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to set the connection string in the constructor of the context.

Answer (score 0):

I face this type of problem
May be you are trying to import null value for a column at database. But the field is not accept null value.

Answer (score -1):

Check in solution properties if single startup project is selected.